# Convert a numeric array of indexes to an ordered array of elements from an associative array of objects indexed by those indexes

Tags: php, arrays

*Note: I should be clear my desire is to do this functionally, in one statement. I can do this easily with loops but that's not what I'm interested in.*

I have two arrays: a numeric array of indexes, A, and an associative array, B, of objects O indexed by the elements of array A.

I want to produce an array of O in the order of the elements of A--in other words, map the indexes into real objects, based on the associative array B.

For example:

```
A = [ 3, 4, 2, 1 ];
B = [ 1=>"one", 2=>"two", 3=>"three", 4=>"four" ]
```

I want:

```
[ "three", "four", "two", "one" ]
```

Also, incidentally I'm also curious to learn what this concept is called. It's kind of like mapping, but specifically involves indexes into another array, as opposed to a function.

Comment: *"I should be clear my desire is to do this functionally, in as few lines as possible--ideally one."* Shorter code != better code.

Comment: No but abstracting away implementation is always a good idea. I don't want to write loops to do what a single function call can.

Comment: You could do: [`array_map(function ($v) use ($b) { return $b[$v]; }, $a);`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qmv4ay)

Comment: `array_map` is still a loop by the way; it might look fancier and it's ever so slightly faster, but that's about it — there's nothing inherently better of this method than doing a simple foreach loop.

Comment: I'm not concerned with performance. I just want the simplest code.

Comment: @NullUserException That's exactly it can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @chaiguy pretty sure `foreach($A as $i) $R[] = $B[$i]; ` is simpler than `array_map(function ($v) use ($b) { return $b[$v]; }, $a); `, considering they both accomplish the same.

Comment: @Mahn The advantage is the latter is inlineable.

Comment: @chaiguy I didn't downvote, though technically that foreach is a one-liner aswell.

Comment: I'm going to leave this up because it's a good question, but I don't appreciate the downvote with no explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NullUserException posted the answer in a comment:

[`array_map(function ($v) use ($b) { return $b[$v]; }, $a);`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qmv4ay)

Comment: Note: This uses anonymous functions, a feature unavailable in older versions (< 5.3.0) of PHP.

Answer (score 4):

```
$A = array(3, 4, 2, 1);
$B = array(1=>"one", 2=>"two", 3=>"three", 4=>"four");

foreach($A as $i) $R[] = $B[$i]; 

var_dump($R);
```

Comment: I want to do this, but *inline*.

Comment: If performance is not an issue this is the way to go. You have to realize that being able to express an algorithm in a short (but slightly convoluted) way is absolutely the wrong way to go about it. Make your algorithms as clear as possible, add comments whenever things are unclear. It doesn't help you right now, but 6 months or a year from now.

Comment: If you don't like PHP syntax go play with Lisp or Python, or wait till version 7 or something. PHP will absorb all other syntax :D

Comment: Omg seriously? Don't tell me how to program. It's a *simple* concept. It needs no more than a single statement.

Comment: In PHP it does. In some other languages it doesn't. This is a fact. You can wish to deny it but PHP syntax is not the prettiest. And yes, I will tell you how to program, because you asked after all ;) No hard feelings.

Comment: You guys are not understanding the question. I know *how* to do it, I want to know if it's already been encapsulated into its own function.

Comment: Why are you not using `array_map(function ($v) use ($b) { return $b[$v]; }, $a); ` ?

Comment: Furthermore, a language is not defined by its conventions, but by it's capabilities. Just because it's not "the PHP way" to do things functionally doesn't mean one should avoid writing functional code.

Comment: @Baba If that works that's exactly what I'm looking for. I got sidetracked with the arguments. :P

Answer (score 1):

I am just adding a little bit, if anyone is still interested in using "array_map".

```
<?php
    $A = array( 3, 4, 2, 1);
    $B = array( 1=>"one", 2=>"two", 3=>"three", 4=>"four" );
    print_r($A);echo '<br/>';
    print_r($B);echo '<br/>';

    function matchAtoB($sourceA, $sourceB)
    {
        global $B;
        return $B[$sourceA];
    }

    $O = array_map("matchAtoB", $A, $B);
    print_r($O);
?>
```

So the function can only receive an element of each array at a time (not the whole array) and it will loop/repeat itself automatically until all elements in the array are processed.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop, you can access the elements right away:

```
$three = $b[$a[0]]; // "three"
$four = $b[$a[1]]; // "four"
$two = $b[$a[2]]; // "two"
$one = $b[$a[3]]; // "one"
```

You could see this as a 'lazy' or 'just in time' way of accomplishing the same goal, but without the ahead cost of indexing the hash map.

If you want the array explicitly, without the additional lookup, you will need a loop.

I'm not sure if this has a name but the combination of a 'datastore' or 'hash map' combined with an ordered array of keys is not an uncommon one.

Comment: Am not sure he can do this for 1000 sets

Comment: The number of sets is not immediately relevant (he also doesn't mention it), other performance characteristics are at play. If he only needs a handful of values from those 1000 sets the just-in-time way I described is likely faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
$order = array(3, 4, 2, 1);
$input = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three', 4 => 'four');
```

Using [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (PHP 5.3 >)

```
$output = array_map(function($v) use($input) { 
  return $input[$v]; 
}, $order);
```

However, this is essentially the same as doing the following:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($order as $o) {
  $output[] = $input[$o];
}
```

I can't honestly see a shorter way of doing this.